# Facing problem with tabularx

Tags: tabularx

I am trying to create a table. However, I am facing problems with rules and formatting. Please have a look at the latex code.

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcommand{\gmc}\[2\]{\multicolumn{#1}{@{}#2@{}}}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|s|s|s|}

        \hline
        Mean cure time in cells & \gmc{3}{c}{Cell frequency} \\\toprule\toprule
                        & Male     & Female  & Total     \\ \midrule
        Drugtakers         & 4 (80)       & 7 (20) & 4.6         \\ \midrule
        Non Drugtakers     & 3 (20)       & 6  (80)  & 5.4     \\ \midrule
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just +1 mico's answer as it explains tabularx  use but there is never really any point to using tabularx if all the columns are X or p as you know in advance what the column widths need to be so you may as well just use tabular and p columns. tabularx really only makes sense if some of the columns are l r or c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two issues in your code. First, if you want to have three columns of type `s`, defined via `\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X}`, you should set the type of the first column not to `X` but to `Z`, where `Z` should be defined via `\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hsize=2.5\hsize}X}`. Note that the sum of the `\hsize` fractions has to equal the number of columns of (possibly modified) `X`. (Incidentally, it might make sense to add a `\centering` instruction to the definition of the `s` column type.)

Second, since you're using the `booktabs` package and its macros to obtain well-spaced horizontal rules, you shouldn't use any vertical rules in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize= .5\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hsize=2.5\hsize}X}  
\begin{document}
     \noindent
     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Zsss} % Check: 2.5 + 3 * 0.5 = 4
     \toprule
     Mean cure time in cells & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Cell frequency}\\
     \midrule
                        & Male     & Female   & Total   \\
        Drugtakers      & 4 (80)   & 7 (20)   & 4.6     \\
        Non Drugtakers  & 3 (20)   & 6  (80)  & 5.4  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```